# creating a column which keeps a running count of consecutive values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization, running-count

I am trying to create a column (“consec”) which will keep a running count of consecutive values in another (“binary”) without using loop. This is what the desired outcome would look like:

```
.    binary consec
1       0      0
2       1      1
3       1      2
4       1      3
5       1      4
5       0      0
6       1      1
7       1      2
8       0      0
```

However, this...

```py
df['consec'][df['binary']==1] = df['consec'].shift(1) + df['binary']
```

results in this...

```
.  binary   consec
0     1       NaN
1     1       1
2     1       1
3     0       0
4     1       1
5     0       0
6     1       1
7     1       1
8     1       1
9     0       0
```

I see other posts which use grouping or sorting, but unfortunately, I don't see how that could work for me.

Comment: You say "consecutive", but 0 and 1 are different and you still increase the counter.  So it feels more like you want to reset the counter at each zero.  What do you want to happen there are two zeros in a row?

Comment: good point - poor description, I do indeed want to reset the counter at each zero. so consecutive 0s in df['binary'] would generate 0s in df['consec'].

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the compare-cumsum-groupby pattern (which I *really* need to getting around to writing up for the documentation), with a final `cumcount`:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"binary": [0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0]})
>>> df["consec"] = df["binary"].groupby((df["binary"] == 0).cumsum()).cumcount()
>>> df
   binary  consec
0       0       0
1       1       1
2       1       2
3       1       3
4       0       0
5       0       0
6       1       1
7       1       2
8       0       0
```

---

This works because first we get the positions where we want to reset the counter:

```
>>> (df["binary"] == 0)
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5     True
6    False
7    False
8     True
Name: binary, dtype: bool
```

The cumulative sum of these gives us a different id for each group:

```
>>> (df["binary"] == 0).cumsum()
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    2
5    3
6    3
7    3
8    4
Name: binary, dtype: int64
```

And then we can pass this to `groupby` and use `cumcount` to get an increasing index in each group.

Comment: Would be a nice addition to the documentation, possibly in the Cookbook.

Comment: mind blown. is there any reason this wouldn't work for a panel in place of the dataframe if pan['A'] = df ?

Comment: disregard DSM - figured it out. thanks for your help!

Comment: This does not work correctly if the first element is 1.

Answer (score 3):

For those who ended up here looking for an answer to the "misunderstood" version: 
To reset count for each change in the ***binary*** column, so that ***consec*** does "keep a running count of consecutive values", the following seems to work:

```
df["consec2"] = df["binary"].groupby((df["binary"] <> df["binary"].shift()).cumsum()).cumcount()
```

[image]