# Count of unique rows based on preceding row - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to return unique rows from multiple columns in a `df`. The issue is I want to include the same set of values if they don't appear in the previous row. This is a little hard to explain so I'll display it;

```
df = pd.DataFrame({   
        'Time' : ['2019-08-02 09:50:10.1','2019-08-02 09:50:10.2','2019-08-02 09:50:10.3','2019-08-02 09:50:10.4','2019-08-02 09:50:10.5','2019-08-02 09:50:10.6','2019-08-02 09:50:10.7','2019-08-02 09:50:10.8','2019-08-02 09:50:10.9','2019-08-02 09:50:11.0'],
        'Code1' : ['A','A','B','B','C','C','A','A','B','B'],    
        'Code2' : ['B','B','A','A','B','B','B','B','A','A'],    
        'Code3' : [np.nan,np.nan,'C','C','A','A','C','C','C','C'],                                   
        })


df = df[df.iloc[:, 1:].shift().ne(df.iloc[:, 1:]).any(axis=1)].reset_index(drop = True)
```

Intended Output:

```
                    Time Code1 Code2 Code3
0  2019-08-02 09:50:10.1     A     B   NaN
1  2019-08-02 09:50:10.3     B     A     C
2  2019-08-02 09:50:10.5     C     B     A
3  2019-08-02 09:50:10.7     A     B     C
4  2019-08-02 09:50:10.9     B     A     C
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a sentinel value for the nulls, then group on the result.

The `groupby` is a variant of the [*shift-cumsum* pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33130586/python-pandas-creating-a-column-which-keeps-a-running-count-of-consecutive-val).

```
sentinel = 99999999
mask = df[cols].fillna(sentinel).ne(df[cols].fillna(sentinel).shift())
>>> df.groupby(
        mask.any(axis=1).cumsum(), 
        sort=False,
        as_index=False
    ).first()
                    Time Code1 Code2 Code3
0  2019-08-02 09:50:10.1     A     B   NaN
1  2019-08-02 09:50:10.3     B     A     C
2  2019-08-02 09:50:10.5     C     B     A
3  2019-08-02 09:50:10.7     A     B     C
4  2019-08-02 09:50:10.9     B     A     C
```

Answer (score 1):

First we use `iloc` to select the correct columns, then we use `shift`to check if current row is not equal to the next one. Finally we use `any` over `axis=1 (columns)`. Because `A B C` and `B A C` are different, but have `C` in common:

```
df[df.iloc[:, 1:].shift().ne(df.iloc[:, 1:]).any(axis=1)]
```

Or the same, but written down little less concise:

```
mask = df.iloc[:, 1:].shift().ne(df.iloc[:, 1:])
df[mask.any(axis=1)]
```

```
                    Time Code1 Code2 Code3
0  2019-08-02 09:50:10.1     A     B     C
2  2019-08-02 09:50:10.3     B     A     C
4  2019-08-02 09:50:10.5     C     B     A
6  2019-08-02 09:50:10.7     A     B     C
8  2019-08-02 09:50:10.9     B     A     C
```

Comment: Thanks @Erfan, what is the df contained NaN values though? I'll update the sample df.